# Computing PI in Python 2, how to stop answer truncating

Tags: python, decimal

please go easy on me, I've been learning Python about a week!
I thought I'd try calculating Pi using the Rumanujan formula. I am confident I was able to code that correctly.
My answer is truncating and I'd like it to be represented with 200 dp. In C I'd use malloc to do this perhaps but I understand that Python doesn't work that way.
The learning point I'd like to take away from this is: Is the truncation caused by the limit of representing a float, and if so is it possible to fix?

Thanks.

```
import math
from decimal import *

getcontext().prec = 200
def iterate(n):
    sum = 0
    Decimal(sum)
    sum = (math.factorial(4*n))
    sum = (sum/math.pow(math.factorial(n), 4))
    sum = sum*((26390*n +1103)/math.pow(396, (4*n)))
    return sum
ans=0
Decimal(ans)    
print "Choose the number of iterations:\n"
itnum = int(raw_input())

for n in range (0, itnum+1):
    this_iteration = 0
    Decimal(this_iteration)
    this_iteration = iterate(n)
    ans = ans + this_iteration

ans =  ans*(math.pow(8, 0.5)/9801)
ans = 1/ans
print "%.200f" % ans
```

Comment: Note that you have two occurrences of number 200 in your code. You need to change both of them to print more digits. My bet would be that you change the prec at the beginning but not the format string at the end of your script

Comment: even if I use %r it still truncates

Comment: The above question answered my problem

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet

```
sum = 0
Decimal(sum)
```

leaves `sum` set to the `int` 0, and computes and throws away a `Decimal` equivalent.  Use, instead, an **assignment** statement:

```
sum = Decimal(0)
```

Next, you'll need to ensure every intermediate result is also converted appropriately to `Decimal` (and `float`s by default are not).

Personally, I'd recommend using `gmpy2` instead, but then, I'm biased:-).

Comment: ...This confirmed what I discovered from the question cited above, although I declared as a string.